# I am trying to pass a function to a directive i created but it's not working in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I want to add a chip in the above box when i select it from the drop down so i have created a filter for that and i have passed an array to it bt now the function which was adding the chip to the above box is now not working i don't know why.

The controller code:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("appController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.selected = [{
        'id': 1,
        'state': 'UP'
    }, {
        'id': 2,
        'state': 'Delhi'
    }];
    $scope.options = [{
        'id': 1,
        'state': 'UP'
    }, {
        'id': 2,
        'state': 'Delhi'
    }, {
        'id': 3,
        'state': 'Haryana'
    }, {
        'id': 4,
        'state': 'WB'
    }]
    $scope.add = function (item) {
        console.log(item);
        let insert = true;
        item = JSON.parse(item);
        for (let i = 0; i < $scope.selected.length; i++) {
            if (angular.equals(item, $scope.selected[i])) {
                insert = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (insert == true) {
            $scope.selected.push(item);
            $scope.selected = angular.copy($scope.selected);
        }
    };
    $scope.remove = function (item) {
        let a = item;
        let b = $scope.selected.indexOf(a);
        $scope.selected.splice(b, 1);
    };
});
app.directive("filter", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            param: '=',
            array: '=',
            fun: '&'
        },
        template: "<div ><select ng-change='fun(items)' ng-model='items'><option value='' selected disabled hidden>Choose Here</option> <option ng-repeat='item in array' value={{item}}> {{item.state}}</option> </select>"
    };
});
```

And the view:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="appController">
    <div>
        <div class="chip" ng-repeat="chips in selected">
          {{ chips.state }}
          <span class="closebtn" ng-click="remove(chips)">&times;</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <filter array='options' fun='add(param)'></filter>
</body>
```

The complete code can be found in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sshf1bb3/).

Comment: @Roby Rodriguez  a little bug in your template, modify it as  <div ><select ng-change='fun({param: items})' ng-model='items'><option value='' selected disabled hidden>Choose Here</option> <option ng-repeat='item in array' value={{item}}> {{item.state}}</option> </select></div>

Comment: it was part of the original question - I just did a copy-paste & format so that it might get solved some day :)

Answer (score 2):

I've had a look at this code. Apart from a few errors, the only problem I see is passing data from the directive scope back to the parent. My suggestion would be to refactor the directive as:

```
app.directive("filter", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      // selection: '=',
      array: '=',
      fun: '&'
    },
    template: `<div>
  <select ng-change='fun({ selection: selection })' ng-model='selection'>
    <option value='' selected disabled hidden>Choose Here</option>
    <option ng-repeat='item in array' value={{item}}> {{item.state}}</option>
  </select>
</div>`
  };
});
```

as you can see, you don't really need `selection` in the parent, as it belongs to the 'filter' component. However, you share this data by passing it to the `fun` attribute (which is the function you call on selection change).


A simplified version of the controller would then be:

```
$scope.add = function(selection) {
  var item = JSON.parse(selection);
  for (let i = 0; i < $scope.selected.length; ++i) {
    if ($scope.selected[i].id === item.id) {
      return;
    }
  }
  $scope.selected.push(item);
};

$scope.remove = function(item) {
  let index = $scope.selected.indexOf(item);
  $scope.selected.splice(index, 1);
};
```

A working version of the initial fiddle can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sshf1bb3/1/).

Answer (score 0):

change below line in your directory

```
template: "<div ><select ng-change='fun(items)' ng-model='items'><option value='' selected disabled hidden>Choose Here</option> <option ng-repeat='item in array' value={{item}}> {{item.state}}</option> </select>"
```

to

```
template: "<div ><select ng-change='fun({param: items})' ng-model='items'><option value='' selected disabled hidden>Choose Here</option> <option ng-repeat='item in array' value={{item}}> {{item.state}}</option> </select></div>"
```